# Web API Design: Form POST'ing key-value pairs: JSON or checkbox style?

Tags: api, forms

Design question for RESTful APIs: one of the input parameters to my API (that is, the data sent from the client to my API) is a dictionary (hash / key-value pairs). What's the best way to encode this so that the API can be easily invoked from web pages as well as scripts/programming languages?

My first thought was to json encode the object, something like this:

```
var data = {a:'one', b:'two'};
form_paramter_x = JSON.stringify(data);
```

and decode on the server:

```
data = simplejson.loads( request.POST['form_paramter_x'] )
```

The alternative would be to encode as key-value pairs html-form-checkbox style:

```
form_param_x=a:one&form_param_x=b:two
```

The latter alternative would require ad-hoc parsing of the key and value (the "a:one" part), and generally seems less clean, but also seems closer to a basic HTML form, which is probably a good thing.

Which of these is cleaner? Or is there another better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're designing your API for other parties to use, I'd consider what is going to be easiest for them to encode for. JSON is widely supported these days, so that isn't a deal breaker. In the end, I'd go w/ whichever is easier for your clients to code. Emotionally, I'm leaning towards the JSON encoding.